# Using Android Annotation in an existing project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-annotations

I am trying to you use Android Annotations (https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) in an existing project. I cannot convert the whole project to use Annotations. Can I have some activities that utilize annotations and some acitivites that doesn't use Annotations.

But When I did that, some functionalities stopped working. Like If I used only -

```
@ViewById(R.id.find)
public Button FIND;
...
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ...
   if (FIND != null) {
        FIND.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
   ...
}
```

OnClick on the button doesn't work. Is it mandatory to use @Click annotation.

Can't I just use annotations only where I wish to have. And other parts of the code be the old code without annotations. Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please read the doc more carefully. The injected views are first available in the `@AfterViews` annotated methods:

```
@AfterViews
void afterViews() {
  // you can use injected views here
}
```

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Injecting-Views#afterviews

Answer (score 0):

First of all please respect coding convention, you can find ax explanation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Then, for your question, you can use code of both types: native android and android annotations one.
If you inflate a view using @ViewById annotation, you must keep in mind that the injection of the view is done at a certain point of the execution, so before of that your variable will be null.
As WonderCsabo reccommended to you, use injected views inside of @AfterViews annotated method.

Otherwise, if you want to mantain android native syntax, you MUST instantiate your view manually with findViewById method. Obviously after that you have setted activity's layout